# カノニカルについて

Tags: html

カノニカルについて
PCサイトがもともとあって、SP専用サイトだけを作ってほしいと言われて作りました。

SPサイトをメインのサイトとして、PCはおまけとして残してほしいと言われています。

両方のサイトは、ファイル名が違うが、両方とも残す場合は、PCサイトにカノニカルをつけて
やればそれだけで問題ないと考えて良いでしょうか？

PCサイトのみに下記を記載

```
<head>

<link rel=”canonical” href=”http://www.example.com/sp” />

</head>
```

こうすれば内容がかぶっていたも問題ないですよね。

Comment: 「問題ない」かどうかは、何を問題と考えるのかによって変わってきますので、そこら辺を整理してもらわないと適切な回答は得にくいように思います。`canonical`の使い道がSEO対策なのは丸わかりなんで、「SEO的に」と限定してみても、目的がわからないとなんとも言えないです。「PC版の内容もSP版の内容もほぼ同じであり、PCからPC版に出てくるキーワードなどで検索した場合も、`href`に示したSP版サイトに誘導したい」と言うなら「問題ない」でしょうし、「いやいや、おまけであるPC版サイトとSP版サイトは別物で、異なるページを一緒くたにされたくない」と言うのなら問題大有りでしょう。どのような意味、どのような目的で「問題」ないことを確かめたいのでしょうか?

Comment: 同じファイルとして、SPだけ評価されればOKというケースです。

Comment: 十分クリアでないんですが、要は「PC版で検索してSP版サイト」が出てきて問題ない、と言うことでしょうか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googleは、類似ページや重複ページがある場合に、正規ページを指定することを勧めています。

・[Search Console ヘルプ](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=ja)

そこには、正規ページを指定する方法が、数種類記載されていますが、`canonical`による方法もその一つです。

一方、SP専用サイトを作って、PCサイトを残すということであれば、別の方法があります。

・ [google モバイルSEOの各種設定 別々の URL](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls?hl=ja)

こちらの方法だとPCで検索した場合は、PCサイトの方が表示されますが、前者の場合はSP専用サイトが表示されるようになります。

どちらがベターかを判断されて設定すればいいと思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。PCサイトにカノニカルを入れてSPサイトを指定すれば、SPサイトが公式になって、PCサイトの評価もうつってくれるのですね。

Comment: 上記の2つの方法はSEO的には同等の効果だと思います。